# How to hide ag-grid if rowData is null?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I have a use case where the `ag-grid` (Angular Grid) I am using must not appear at all if the rowData is null that is returned from the Model code.

As of now I am unable to find a way to do it at the grid level.

What would be the right way to implement this? If hiding the div element is the way to do it, how does one doit in aright way from JavaScript?

Comment: There are many solutions for this problem and if you post code (or create example with jsfiddle or plunker - will be the best) it will really help to give a better advise.

Comment: it's hard to make a suggestion without seeing the code you have, but using `ng-if="rowData"` should work....

Comment: I don't think that `ag-grid` stands for "Angular Grid". Do you use something like `ng-grid` instead?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to hide the grid if no rows, then use an ng-if or an ng-show, pointing to the gridOptions.data.

```
<div ng-grid="gridOptions" ng-show="gridOptions.rowData.length>0"/>
```

or

```
<div ng-grid="gridOptions" ng-if="gridOptions.rowData.length>0"/>
```

If you use show, then the grid will stay there, but Angular will apply css to hide the element.

If you use if, then the grid directive will not be initialised by AngularJS until you have data present in rowData.