# ag-grid Grouping - Hide rows with null values

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I am trying to display a balance sheet with several levels using grouping in *ag-grid*. It works - but the data has `null` where the hierarchy skips levels, and I want to hide these rows - example:

> ```
> Level0 - Level1 - Level2 - AccountName - Value
> Assets  - null   - null   - Cash - $10,000
> Liabilities - Payables - Short Term - Invoices - $5,000
> ```

So in my grid, the `Liabilities` hierarchy looks fine, but the `Assets` hierarchy has two `null` levels between `Assets` and `Cash`. I want to hide the `null` rows. See attached picture:

[image: Balance Sheet with nulls]

I am trying to make this working using the construct mentioned by Niall [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31816122/5047996):

```
<div ng-grid="gridOptions" ng-show="gridOptions.rowData.length>0"/>
```

or:

```
<div ng-grid="gridOptions" ng-if="gridOptions.rowData.length>0"/>
```

However, my `rowData` is not `null`, but the `groupColumnDef` is.

Do I need `gridOptions.rowNode.data` in my `ng-if`/`ng-show`? Not sure how to solve this.

The controller code is as follows:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('BalShtController', BalShtController);

BalShtController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

function BalShtController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.title = 'Balance Sheet';

    var columnDefs = [
      { headerName: "No.", field: "GlNumber", sort: 'asc', hide: 'true' },
      { headerName: "Value", field: "Value", cellRenderer: currencyFormat, cellStyle: currencyCssFunc, width: 200 }

    ];



    $scope.gridOptions = {
        columnDefs: columnDefs,
        rowData: null,
        enableFilter: true,
        enableColResize: true,
        onReady: function () {
            $scope.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit()
        },

        groupKeys: ['GlPartnerLevel1', 'GlPartnerLevel2', 'GlPartnerLevel3', 'GlPartnerLevel4', 'GlName'],
        groupAggFields: ['Value'],
        groupDefaultExpanded: 3,

        groupIncludeFooter: true,
        groupColumnDef: {
            headerName: "Detail",
            field: "TxTransactionDate",
            width: 300,
            cellRenderer: {
                renderer: 'group',
                footerValueGetter: '"Total (" + x + ")"',
                padding: 5
            }
        },

    };
$http.get("http://localhost:39016/api/BalanceSheet")
            .then(function (res) {
                $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData(res.data);

            });
    }
})();
```

Comment: First : 
The Array of object you have before mapping, make a seperate function that filter the array from Null objects and make a new one that has no null object.

2nd :
Feed the new array to the ag-Grid.

This is an alternative , but will take more performance, so I dont count it as answer unless you confirm it.